# Strange animation when removing item from RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView populated by the  `val microphones: MutableList<Microphone>`. There's a button in the row layout to remove that item from the list, which I've managed to get functioning, but the animation is going wrong. It looks like when the recyclerView updates, it removes the last item in the list, then the correct item, and then the whole list below the removed item animates to the correct state.

Here's the relevant bits of the recyclerView adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    val microphones: MutableList<Microphone>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val cellForRow = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.favorites_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(cellForRow)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return microphones.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val microphone = microphones[position]

    holder.bind(microphone)

    holder.favoritesButton.setOnClickListener {
        microphones.remove(microphone)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
}

class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val modelText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.model_textView)
    val brandText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.brand_textView)
    val favoritesButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnFavorite)

    fun bind(
        microphone: Microphone,
    ) {

        modelText.text = microphone.model
        brandText.text = microphone.brand
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screen recording of the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS8Vw.jpg

Comment: I believe the problem probably is how you are removing items from the microphones, could you show us?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, beyond the provided code. `microphones` is a MutableList of my `Microphone` object, which is inherited from the parent fragment. I'm removing the appropriate entry with an onClick Listener for the `ImageButton` in its row, and just removing the entry from the list in onBindViewHolder. What other information would be helpful?